# Run command if player is NOT matching DataTag

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have a huge problem: I want to set a players `HPLUranium` score to 9 whenever he wears an anti-radiation suit - easy, I do this like that:

```
scoreboard players set @p HPLUranium 9 {Inventory:[{Slot:103b,id:minecraft:leather_helmet,tag:{display:{Name:Nuclear Helmet,color:10066328}}},{Slot:102b,id:minecraft:leather_chestplate,tag:{display:{Name:Nuclear Tunic,color:10066328}}},{Slot:101b,id:minecraft:leather_leggings,tag:{display:{Name:Nuclear Pants,color:10066328}}},{Slot:100b,id:minecraft:leather_boots,tag:{display:{Name:Nuclear Boots,color:10066328}}}]}
```

But the problem is... how do I make him LOSE this 9 whenever it's not true? Like Conditional command block but opposite, command block that only runs when the one behind him say "false".

I tried to make command block repeating setting `HPLUranium` to 0, and next to it Chain command block with command showed up there, but it was sometimes changing to 0 for... maybe a tick long when it should be 9, it may cause problems.

Any ideas how to run command if player IS NOT MATCHING DataTag?

Comment: The method you already tried is the only method I think that there is, but it should always work.

Comment: Not sure, becouse as I said sometimes 9 changes to 0 for a few ticks long... it may be a problem :/

Comment: @HardnerPL in that case, your setup is wrong somehow. There should not be any flickering involved. Two chain command blocks triggering after one another should work.

Comment: @MrLemon You're right i guess, looks like it can't be a problem - i made repeating command block trying to kill me if it's 0, but even if it "changed" to 0 i wasn't killed :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use exclamation marks in Minecraft commands?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/288688/how-to-use-exclamation-marks-in-minecraft-commands)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a repeating command block with the following command and keep note of its coordinates:

```
testfor @p {Inventory:[{Slot:103b,id:minecraft:leather_helmet,tag:{display:{Name:Nuclear Helmet,color:10066328}}},{Slot:102b,id:minecraft:leather_chestplate,tag:{display:{Name:Nuclear Tunic,color:10066328}}},{Slot:101b,id:minecraft:leather_leggings,tag:{display:{Name:Nuclear Pants,color:10066328}}},{Slot:100b,id:minecraft:leather_boots,tag:{display:{Name:Nuclear Boots,color:10066328}}}]}
```

Then, have another repeating command block with the following command, replacing X, Y, and Z with the coordinates of the first repeating command block:

```
testforblock X Y Z command_block -1 {SuccessCount:0}
```

and it will point to a last repeating command block set to `Conditional` with the following command:

```
scoreboard players set @p HPLUranium 0
```

All command blocks should be set to `Always Active`.

When the first command block fails, the second command succeeds because the `SuccessCount` is `0`. This causes the third command block to activate, because conditional command blocks activate when a command block pointing into them succeeds.

When the player **is** wearing the anti-radiation suit, the second command block will fail because `SuccessCount` will not be `0`, and the player's `HPLUranium` score will not change.