# How to testfor somebody that does not have a item in their inventory in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to make a command that will kill anybody that does not have a trip wire called Midget passing in their inventory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use exclamation marks in Minecraft commands?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/288688/how-to-use-exclamation-marks-in-minecraft-commands)

Answer (score 2):

create a scoreboard objective called "HaveKey"(or whatever name you want)

```
/scoreboard objectives add HaveKey dummy HaveKey
```

make a scoreboard that gives all players who have a trip wire called midget a score of 1 in HaveKey

```
/scoreboard players set @a HaveKey 1 {Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:tripwire_hook",tag:{display:{Name:"Midget"}}}]}
```

then kill all players that do have a score of 0 in this scoreboard

```
/kill @a[score_HaveKey=0]
```

and there you have it

Comment: When using scoreboards, players will not have a score at all if they haven't been given one, meaning `score_HaveKey=0` will not find anybody. As well, the mechanism will fail if the player removes the item from their inventory because they will still have a score of 1. You will want to set their score to 0 first, which both allows that detection and allows `/kill` to work.

Answer (score -1):

You would need to set up a /testfor command in a command block that searches for an item in a players inventory (see video) then put another command block that has this command `kill@e[type=player]` connected to it. This command will kill every player entity and because of the testfor command, it will only activate when someone has the item in their inventory. even though the video says 1.8 I tried it myself yesterday in 1.11.2 and it works just fine

Disclaimer: This video is not owned by me, please visit Dragnoz's youtube channel to see more videos like this

video tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S6rFa7Oi7mU)

Comment: As stated, "This command will kill every player entity". The question was to kill only the relevant players. `/testfor` in this case is useless. If one player doesn't have the relevant item, then **all** players are killed as a result, not just the player without the item.