# Test for a player who isn't wearing a helmet? [1.12.2]

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to set the score 'ToxicJungleSafe' to 0 if a player isn't wearing a helmet in 1.12.2.

So far I have tried using ArmorItems tag, as well as Inventory tag. minecraft:air doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use exclamation marks in Minecraft commands?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/288688/how-to-use-exclamation-marks-in-minecraft-commands)

Answer (score 0):

**[1.12-]**

Repeat this:

```
/scoreboard players set @a ToxicJungleSafe 0
/scoreboard players set @a[nbt={Inventory:[{Slot:103b}]}] ToxicJungleSafe 1
```

**[1.13+]**

1.13 syntax makes this easier, and condenses it into one command.

This command will give players a score of 1 if the player has an item in their 103rd inventory slot, which is the armor slot for the head.

```
execute as @a store result score @s ToxicJungleSafe if entity @s[nbt={Inventory:[{Slot:103b}]}]
```

If you want the player to need all 4 armor pieces equipped in order to be 'safe', just add the other slots:

```
execute as @a store result score @s ToxicJungleSafe if entity @s[nbt={Inventory:[{Slot:100b},{Slot:101b},{Slot:102b},{Slot:103b}]}]
```

Comment: You can also just use `/execute unless data` in 1.13+ and don't need a score at all, you can just execute the command from there.